# PHP regular expression: Match exact word without other characters

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that is like this `?supercategory=1&category=14&page=2` and I have a function that removes a selected filter from within that string and then returns it.

My regular expression is `preg_replace('/(category=[0-9]+)&?/', '', $queryString)`

Obviously the above code matches `supercategory`, but I want to match category in the string, not supercategory

How do I make this possible ?

I want to mention that the position of `category` and `supercategory` in the string can be changed.

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply use [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), unset() the category element, then use [http_build_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to recreate the query string?

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you very much, that was way easier than what I was doing. Any way I can mark your comment as the accepted answer?

Comment: You can't mark a comment as an answer, but I have provided an actual answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to use a regexp, this is a lot simpler using PHP's built-in [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), unset() the `category` element, then use [http_build_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to recreate the query string

```
$dataString = 'supercategory=1&category=14&page=2';
parse_str($dataString, $urlArguments);
if (isset($urlArguments['category'])) {
    unset($urlArguments['category']);
}
$dataString = http_build_query($urlArguments);
var_dump($dataString);
```